# What is the equivalent of the following statement in java?

Tags: java, dart

I'm writing a javafx application and I would like to call functions and set variables in the same statement where I declare an instance of a class.

I can do this in dart like the following code, but can I do this in java?

```
class MyClass{
  int someVar =1;
  someFun(){
     print("something");
  }
}

void main(){
 MyClass newClass = new MyClass()
  ..someVar = 2 // how can I do this in java?
  ..someFun();

 print(newClass.someVar);

}
```

Comment: either using setters or (not so nice idea) declaring those fields public

Comment: The way you do it in the last line, EG: `newClass.someVar = 2`

Comment: Java doesn't support this; it's a hassle. Both Groovy and Kotlin make it easy.

Comment: oh, ok, chrylis -on-strike-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't do this in Java - at least not in the Dart style. The double dot (..) notation is a Dart language feature, which Java simply does not have. However, for this simple example, you can achive the same result like this:

```
class MyClass {
    int someVar = 1;

    MyClass setSomeVar(int i) {
        someVar = i;
        return this;
    }

    MyClass someFun() {
        System.out.println("something");
        return this;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass newClass = new MyClass()
            .setSomeVar(2)
            .someFun();

    System.out.println(newClass.someVar);
}
```

As in Dart, this only works for methods that (normally) do not have a return value (e.g. `void` methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that either using setters or (not so nice idea) declaring those fields public:

```
class MyClass{
  int someVar = 1;
  void setSomeVar(int x){
    someVar = x;
  }
  someFun(){
     print("something");
  }
}

void main(){
 MyClass newClass = new MyClass()
  newClass.serSomeVar(2);
  ..someFun();

 print(newClass.someVar);

}

----

class MyClass{
  public int someVar = 1;

  someFun(){
     print("something");
  }
}

void main(){
 MyClass newClass = new MyClass()
  newClass.someVar = 2;
  ..someFun();

 print(newClass.someVar);
}
```

Comment: please notice that I said I'm using javafx framework so I can't change the class body and make its variables public or define setters because the framework source code is not changeable

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your question the following would solve your problem

You will need to declare your variable as public in the class, you will replace

```
int someVar = 1
```

with

```
public int someVar = 1
```

and in the function you can call it like this

```
void main(){
  MyClass newClass = new MyClass()
  newClass.someVar = 2 // how can I do this in java?
  newClass.someFun();

  print(newClass.someVar);    
}
```

A Better way would be to use Setters and Getters but you can start with this.

Hope this helps

Comment: please notice that I said I'm using javafx framework so I can't change the class body and make its variables public or define setters because the framework source code is not changeable

Comment: @Ammar JavaFX is just Java and all classes in the framework provide appropriate accessors when needed, so I don't understand this statement.  Can you provide code for an actual specific example of a thing you need to change and cannot?  Perhaps by editing your question if appropriate or asking a new one.